# Graphics tool to rename files in batch mode?

Tags: linux, file-management, gui

I need a tool to help me rename files as a group. What I want to do is to drag a list of files into the tool and name them according to some criteria, mainly `filename 01.ext`, `filename 02.ext` etc. My immediate concerning is to rename files created by snapshot tools like Shutter and VLC by a prefix, such as the subject's name, then the numerical suffix.

A tool that accomplishes something like this is [AdvancedRenamer](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/) but it is a Windows program.

Comment: Related (on our sister-site): [An Ubuntu/Linux alternative of Bulk Rename Utility for Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/511862/68291) Info from the "outer world": [How to Rename Files in Linux](https://www.maketecheasier.com/rename-files-in-linux/)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [pyRenamer](https://launchpad.net/pyrenamer).

> With pyRenamer you can change the name of several files at the same
>   time easily.
>
> - You can use patterns to rename files.
> - You can use search & replace to rename files.
> - You can use common substitutions.
> - You can manually rename selected files.
> - You can rename images using their metadata.
> - You can rename music using its metadata.

Most Linux distributions should have pyRenamer in their repositories.

Here's a screenshot of the program in action. I typically use it to rename pictures based on the EXIF metadata and the pattern desired:

[image: pyRenamer in action]

One of the things I like is the preview functionality, which enables you to view the result of the renaming without actually renaming the files, a sort of dry run.

It should be quite easy to apply the renaming criteria you need for your files.

Answer (score 1):

[Thunar](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/start) (the default file manager for Xubuntu - but you can install it on other distributions) provides a bulk renaming feature which is very handy and has a simple GUI. It allows to rename multiple files at once numbering them, and even changing the extension. You can find a brief overview of the feature [here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/bulk-renamer/start). Also if you have a distribution with KDE environment you can try [KRename](http://www.krename.net/home/).